# Understanding proof for cardioid into coffee cup

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, envelope

I've been trying to learn more about envelope of lines and came over [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1553478/1200542) for the cardioid inside a cup. I have arrived at the two parametric equations which I've written in matrix form.

$$\begin{pmatrix}cos3\theta & -sin3\theta\\\ sin3\theta & 1+cos3\theta\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{3} cos\theta-\frac{2}{3}cos2\theta \\ sin\theta\ sin2\theta \end{pmatrix}$$

I'm using the Cramer's Rule approach to get a general solution for x and y in terms of $\theta$, and so far I've gotten the determinant. The final answer in the linked proof has written the final solution in the cartesian form for a cardioid, $(\frac{1}{3}(2−2),\frac{1}{3}(2−2))$. But, I've been struggling to get $D_x$ and $D_y$, I don't know which trigonometric identities to use and I seem to be going in circles!

I would appreciate if some direction to solve this can be given!

Comment: What do you mean, "solve this"?  Get $(x,y)^t$?  Multiply on the left by the matrix inverse.

Comment: slightly related: [Constraints on conical coffee cup constructions of cardioids & catacaustics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2860099/284619) and the linked [Mathologer video](https://youtu.be/qhbuKbxJsk8)

Comment: Hello, sorry, I should have specified. I'm trying to get a general solution for x and y in terms of theta.

Comment: *Mathematica*: $$x = \frac{1}{6} \left(-3 \sin (3 \theta )+2 \cos (\theta )-4 \cos (2 \theta )+3 \sin (\theta
   ) \left(\frac{1}{\cos (\theta )-\frac{1}{2}}+1\right)\right)$$ and $$y= -\frac{2}{3} \sin ^2\left(\frac{3 \theta }{2}\right) \csc (3 \theta ) (\cos (\theta )-2
   \cos (2 \theta )-3 \sin (\theta ) \sin (2 \theta ) \cot (3 \theta ))$$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I wonder what $y(x)$ looks like

Comment: I'm just hyperlinked the proof I looked at, they seemed to have written the final solution in the standard cartesian form for a cardioid, $(\frac{1}{3}(cos2\theta-2cos\theta),\frac{1}{3}(2sin\theta-sin2\theta))$. Is there any way to simplify this expression to that form?