# Why does the light at the bottom of a mug trace a cardiod?

Tags: physics

Everytime I go to grab a mug I see a shape in the bottom, which looks oddly like the cardioid. Is there some mathematical/physics answer to this phenomenon?

Comment: It is called a "caustic."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_%28optics%29

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cardioid in coffee mug?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550259/cardioid-in-coffee-mug)